# Delegate as parameter in C# class constructor

Tags: c#, delegates, constructor, pass-by-reference

Hi i have a class with a delegate as a parameter as shown in the code, but i get the errors
`Error  1   Type expected   ...\Classes\Class1.cs   218 33  Classes` and
`Error  2   ; expected  ...\Classes\Class1.cs   218 96  Classes`. How do i fix the issue? Thanks in advance! I'm trying to pass it byref so when a class initializes, some method of it is attached to the delegate.

```
public constructor(ref delegate bool delegatename(someparameters))
{
    some code
}
```

Comment: is this really lifted from a C# code file? it looks very strange indeed

Comment: Constructors in c# are defined as class names.Like class MyClass { public MyClass() { ... } }

Comment: of course i changed it a little...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot declare the delegate type in the constructor. You need to first declare the delegate type, and then you can use it in the constructor:

```
public delegate bool delegatename(someparameters);

public constructor(ref delegatename mydelegate)
{
   some code...
}
```

Comment: Why the `ref`? isn't it a reference type? Also, what is it going to pass back?

Answer (score 5):

You can pass something like `Action<T>` ... not sure why you want to pass it by reference though. For example, you can have a method like this one:

```
static void Foo(int x, Action<int> f) {
    f(x + 23);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
int x = 7;
Foo(x, p => { Console.WriteLine(p); } );
```

Comment: In his case it would probably be more appropriate with a `Func<..., bool>` it looks like.

Answer (score 4):

1 - Why you're using the `ref` keyword?

2 - the `constructor` is the class name? 
if not, you're doing this wrong, different of PHP: `public function __construct( .. ) { }` the constructor is named of class name, for example:

```
class foo { 
   public foo() { } // <- class constructor 
}
```

3 - Normally the types of delegates are void.

You're looking for this?

```
 class Foo {

        public delegate bool del(string foo);

        public Foo(del func) { //class constructor
                int i = 0;
                while(i != 10) {
                        func(i.ToString());
                        i++;
                }
        }
    }
```

Then:

```
class App
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Foo foo = new Foo(delegate(string n) {
                            Console.WriteLine(n);
                            return true; //this is it unnecessary, you can use the `void` type instead.          });
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: There's a rule that delegates should be void?  Tell that to `Func<...>`.

Comment: No,There's not a that rule delegates should be void,it this depends of your case.

Comment: so why did you put that in?  There's no such rule or convention.  Plenty of delegates are non-void.  Perhaps you are thinking of event handlers, which are almost always void, for simplicity.

Comment: +1 as I was looking for a way to have a delegate with parameters that were accessing the values inside the method